# Bull Queues + Typescript: Queues stop when a job fails

Tags: typescript, express

I've looked for similar questions but they have answers that don't really help me in my situation.
For example, I made this code to save actions from a user

```
const actionQueue = new Bull('user_actions', `redis://${process.env.REDIS_HOST}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`, {
    limiter: {
        max: parseInt(process.env.QUEUE_MAX_PROCESS!),
        duration: parseInt(process.env.QUEUE_MAX_TIME!)
    }
});

const actionProcess = async (job: Job) => await ActionService.processAction(job.data);

const addActionToQueue = (data: IAction) => actionQueue.add(data, { priority: 1, delay: 3000});

actionQueue.process(actionProcess);
```

How could I repeat the jobs that failed and the queue would not stop if they failed?

Comment: What does `ActionService.processAction` do? I'm not familiar with Bull queues but I suspect a retry is just adding the same action to the queue if processAction returns a failed job.